Convert moment time to milliseconds
I want to convert moment time to milliseconds.
I have next code:
const moment = require("moment")

const countdown = "00:02:32"
const millis = moment(countdown, "hh:mm:ss")
console.log(millis.milliseconds())

As a result I get 0
Idea is I have some countdown and I want to know hom many milliseconds I need to wait for next operation.

moment.duration(countdown, "HH:mm:ss") creates a duration object from the countdown string.
duration.asMilliseconds() converts the duration into milliseconds.
const moment = require("moment");

const countdown = "00:02:32";
const duration = moment.duration(countdown, "HH:mm:ss");

const millis = duration.asMilliseconds();
console.log(millis); // Output will be 152000 milliseconds (or 2 minutes and 32 seconds)


The milliseconds() method returns only the milliseconds part of the time (e.g., "00:02:32.123" gives 123).
To get the total milliseconds, convert the moment object to a duration:
const moment = require("moment");

const countdown = "00:02:32";
const millis = moment.duration(countdown, "hh:mm:ss").asMilliseconds();
console.log(millis);


Thank you. I thought in this direction but missed for asMilliseconds()
